# Unable to determine number of fit parameters

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to fit a curve on several `x` and `y` points based on my logistic function.

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(logistic, x, y, maxfev=50000)
y_fitted = logistic(x_future, *popt
```

being `y`:

```
array([2.000e+00, 4.000e+00, 6.000e+00, 9.000e+00, 1.300e+01, 2.100e+01,
       3.000e+01, 3.900e+01, 4.100e+01, 5.900e+01, 7.800e+01, 1.120e+02,
       1.690e+02, 2.450e+02, 3.310e+02, 4.480e+02, 6.420e+02, 7.850e+02,
       1.020e+03, 1.280e+03, 1.600e+03, 2.060e+03, 2.362e+03, 2.995e+03,
       3.544e+03])
```

`x`:

```
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.,
       13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24.])
```

and my logistic function:

```
def logistic(x):
    return 1/(a+b*np.exp(-k*x))
```

`a` , `b` and `k` are pre computed, the only valuable input is `x` and should be calculated bases on this function.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If `a`, `b`, and `k` are precomputed, then the function is already known - as in, I'm not sure what the purpose of calling `curve_fit` is. If you are trying to determine those parameters, just change your function to:

```
def logistic(x, a, b, k):
    return 1/(a+b*np.exp(-k*x))
```